# Twitter API 1.1 library for Python 2.4?

Tags: python, twitter, python-2.4

Is there any library for Python 2.4 that supports Twitter API 1.1?

Until recently I've been using tweepy v1.9, which does not support the new Twitter API. However, newer tweepy versions as well as all other Python libraries listed at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries do not seem to support Python 2.4

Perhaps there are older versions of one of the above mentioned that would fulfill both requirements?

Answer (score 1):

tweepy 2.1 works with Python 2.4 and Twitter API 1.1 after some modifications:

> **binder.py - Line 134/136**
>   remove timeout parameter and use
>   `import socket`
> `socket.setdefaulttimeout(self.api.timeout)`
>   instead
>
> **cursor.py - Line 96 and models.py - Line 22/29**
>   change to "normal" `if - else` statement

---

Just as a line of warning: I didn't test all functionality of tweepy. I just used it in a Python 2.4 project for fetching the timeline of some users. So tweepy might require additional modifications for other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this one https://github.com/bear/python-twitter. I used to use Tweepy and the Sixohsix repository on GitHub, but lately, this is the only one I've been able to successfully connect to using the 1.1 API. The spec says that Python must be >= 2.4, so it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately python-twitter does not seem to work with 2.4. The Readme clearly states that it "works with Python versions from 2.5 to 2.7". I cannot even install it without getting errors.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I had read through the docs as well, but when I searched python 2.4 twitter, the specs sheet came up and the requirement had said python >= 2.4. I must have misread it.